# 5 amp circuits because of LED lighting

Tags: led

There are multiple parts to this, but they are connected..

1) With the advent of LED lighting 15 amps is overkill for a dedicated light circuit. A 16 AWG 300-ft-max circuit could be run off a 3A breaker. That would permit 36 x 10 watt lights.

2) Are there any designated lamp sockets that only LED lamps could fit. eg E4, GU 7.5 or whatever. This would make ceiling insulation less of a problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. The first part of your question isn't a question; it's just a statement, and really isn't necessary for the second part. And, the second part comes perilously close to asking for a product, which is off-topic here.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. It's an interesting topic though, and the explanation probably involves the diminishing return on downsizing wire vs. potential higher-current usability. 16 AWG solid wire is probably marginally cheaper (if at all) than 14.

Comment: It may ahead of this time that incandescent lamp replacements forge ahead with an incompatible socket.  What fire safety improvement or cost savings are in buying a 5A breaker with a sealed LED bulb?

Comment: Since you mention 3 amp breakers I’m assuming this is European?

Comment: Do you build a lot of houses? Or are you just armchair theorycrafting?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Would you have this only be allowable in certain wiring methods or all of them? How would you assure the cable/wire has the same durability and tensile strength as existing cables and wires?

Comment: Not an armchair. I am not a qualified electrician but I have rewired numerous houses under the auspices of an electrician. I can only speak for the UK, Canada and US. Canada and US are fairly similar but there are various differences.For example Melni (et al) connectors are not permitted. I am in the process of rewiring one of my apartments. It will all be LED.

Comment: So let me compare to the UK, at least when I was last working there. Lights and power are on different circuits. The power circuits are called ring mains. All three wires (ground, neutral and power) loop back to the breaker box and both are inserted into the connectors. The standard 'fuse' is/was 25 amps. However, as the current could flow in both directions the gauge of wire needed was less. It was also 240 volts. This meant one breaker could service 3.5 times the power of a US 15A breaker.

Comment: Whoops - keep on pressing enter. However all devices that fit into receptacles must have three pins and be individually fused within the plug itself. This means a lamp with a 3 amp fuse would blow out at 720 watts (rather than 1800 in the US). Something like an electric kettle would be a 13 amp breaker = 3KW plus change. It also meant that devices like microwaves, fridges, furnaces, did not need dedicated circuits. There is a drastic saving on wire. To pop the breaker needed 6KW. Morretes do not exist and all connections are screwed down. A 240V belt hurts. Pain is exponential

Comment: Well, the ring main idea is right up there with NEMA 10 in terms of fairly bad ideas, and nobody else in the world does that.  In fact that is what requires  fuses in each device socket, otherwise you could pull 25A or 32A off a single socket and have no protection.  Nobody else fuses sockets.  I don't share the sense of wire savings since each ring has two homeruns. I just don't see much savings in using 16 or 18 for branch circuits, especially since 16 and 18 THHN equivalents cost *more* than 14.,

Comment: The sockets are not fused, the plugs are. Each device has the smallest fuse suitable for that device. In my last Canadian kitchen/den I had 20 circuits. In the UK that would have been 4 or 5. The ring main effectively doubles the current that flows from the beaker. It is self-leveling. There is a device call a megaohmeter used to test the circuit before connection to the breaker. It puts a high voltage(10,000V???) across wires and detects insulation deficiencies. It also can be put across any individual pair to detect arcing / poor joints.  All above may be outdated as this was 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question or whatever. Here's some info.

1) NEC Table 240-.6 (A) lists the circuit breaker trip ratings starting with 15 amps, and NEC Atricle 240.4 (D)(3) tells you you need to connect a #14 AWG conductor to it. Point is your asking why can't we change a standard, and to start the electrical community would have to rewrite a lot of the NEC and then manufacturers would have to embrace it. I would say good luck on trying to get all of that done.

2) Actually reference the last comment that just came up. When you design fixtures just for LED's just like compact fluorescence(see the biax or type PL base lamps), you design them with a specific base that you cannot interchange. Everything else you are looking at are retrofit items that replace an old technology with new. In the meantime we must design lighting loads with the highest rated wattage the fixture will accept whether it is an incandescent or an LED.

Hope this sheds some light.

Comment: Thank you for number 2. I have seen them in Home Depot, but the flexibility of light color, lumens etc is limited. It does however solve the massive IC canister size and that they are pain in a retrofit with foam insulation. I'll shut up now (in my armchair)